# 3 dimension graph (nodes, arcs) using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying to visualize 3d graphs using D3.js. All nodes & arcs are fixed (eg X,Y,Z coordinates are known), no need for Dynamic Force-Directed positioning.

This example, from a commercial library, is great for nodes visualization:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-scatter-draggable

(rotation, different colors, more info shown on hover...).

How can one

- do exactly the same in D3.js ?
- add arcs? (having a list of arcs between nodes). Ideally, it would show the arc strength too, with a wider line when set to stronger.

Closest examples found:

- https://bl.ocks.org/Niekes/d8007a5f71f45ab80a2977a8eb7ab3c9 - doesn't allow 3D rotation, no info on hover, no arcs
- https://medium.com/ninjaconcept/interactive-dynamic-force-directed-graphs-with-d3-da720c6d7811 - no need for dynamic force, not 3D.

Comment: maybe you can look at three.js. D3 is not designed for 3d graphs

Comment: Thanks! Will look into that